# Spring Transaction failed to open on service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions

I wanted to set `@Transactional` on my services instead of my DAOs... in order to open transaction and be able to use some lazy collections within my services without getting some "LazyInitializationException".

Untill now the `@Transactional` were on the DAOs, and transactions were opened and closed when entering in the DAOs and exiting from them.

Now, with `@Transactional` on my services, transactions are not even opened. So the service call the DAO with no transaction opened and we got the folowing exception: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

We're using JPA over Hibernate, here is an extract from our configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"/>  

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

EDIT, thanks for your replys/comments:
So, i'm declaring the @Transactional on the whole service (implementation and not interface) and not on methods in order to be sure that the @Transactional will apply to all.

```
@Transactional
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  public void method1(){...}
  public void method2(){...}
}
```

I also give you the way my DAOs are configured, they all extend the following class:

```
public abstract class JpaDAOSupport {
  protected EntityManager em;
  @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
  }
}
```

EDIT2:
I simplified my application in order to have only 1 service, and 1 DAO.

MyService:

```
@Transactional
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  private MyDAO myDAO;

  public void setMyDAO(MyDAO myDAO) {
    this.myDAO = myDAO;
  }


  @Override
  public void method1() {
    List<String> things = myDAO.getAll();
    System.out.println("Test size: " + things.size());
  }

  @Override
  public void method2() {
    List<String> things = myDAO.getAll();
    for (String thing : things) {
      System.out.println(thing);
    }
  }
}
```

MyDAO

```
@Repository
public class MyDAOImpl extends JpaDAOSupport implements MyDAO {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public List<String> getAll() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("FROM " + Cfg.class.getName());
    List<Cfg> result = query.getResultList();
    List<String> realResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Cfg cfg : result) {
      realResult.add(cfg.getKey());
    }
    return realResult;
  }
}
```

Persistence config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">


  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"/>    

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

  <bean id="my.package.dao.MyDAO" class="my.package.dao.jpa.MyDAOImpl" />

  <bean id="my.package.service.MyService" class="my.package.service.impl.MyServiceImpl" init-method="method1">
    <property name="myDAO" ref="my.package.dao.MyDAO" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Note that i don't have access to the attribute "mode" for tx:annotation-driven.

Here are the spring logs in mode DEBUG of the start up:

```
[...]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'entityManagerFactory'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'entityManagerFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'beanClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'dataSource' of type [javax.sql.DataSource]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'entityManagerFactoryInterface' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'entityManagerInterface' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaDialect' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaDialect]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaProperties' of type [java.util.Properties]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaPropertyMap' of type [java.util.Map]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'nativeEntityManagerFactory' of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'object' of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'objectType' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'persistenceProvider' of type [javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'persistenceProviderClass' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'persistenceUnitInfo' of type [javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'persistenceUnitName' of type [java.lang.String]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'singleton' of type [boolean]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
ingframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean  Building JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'null'
ework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  Bean 'entityManagerFactory' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'entityManagerFactory'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory          Creating [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'advisorAdapterRegistry' of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AdvisorAdapterRegistry]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'applyCommonInterceptorsFirst' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'beanClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'beanFactory' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'customTargetSourceCreators' of type [[Lorg.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.TargetSourceCreator;]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'exposeProxy' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'frozen' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'interceptorNames' of type [[Ljava.lang.String;]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'opaque' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'optimize' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'order' of type [int]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'proxyClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'proxyTargetClass' of type [boolean]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
ework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@7d2796]
ework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@1335207]
ework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils  Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@6bbe7]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1989b5: defining beans [org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,my.package.dao.MyDAO,my.package.service.MyService]; root of factory hierarchy
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'transactionManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'dataSource' of type [javax.sql.DataSource]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'defaultTimeout' of type [int]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'entityManagerFactory' of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'failEarlyOnGlobalRollbackOnly' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaDialect' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaDialect]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaProperties' of type [java.util.Properties]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'jpaPropertyMap' of type [java.util.Map]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'nestedTransactionAllowed' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'resourceFactory' of type [java.lang.Object]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'rollbackOnCommitFailure' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionSynchronization' of type [int]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionSynchronizationName' of type [java.lang.String]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'validateExistingTransaction' of type [boolean]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
rk.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator  Did not attempt to auto-proxy infrastructure class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'advice' of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'adviceBeanName' of type [java.lang.String]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'beanFactory' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'classFilter' of type [org.springframework.aop.ClassFilter]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'order' of type [int]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'perInstance' of type [boolean]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'pointcut' of type [org.springframework.aop.Pointcut]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSource]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory          Creating [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'transactionManager'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
rk.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator  Did not attempt to auto-proxy infrastructure class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSource]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionAttributeSources' of type [[Lorg.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSource;]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionAttributes' of type [java.util.Properties]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'transactionManager' of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO'
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [my.package.dao.jpa.JpaDAOSupport]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [my.package.dao.jpa.JpaDAOSupport]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'em' of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager]
amework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata  Found injected method on class [my.package.dao.jpa.MyDAOImpl]: PersistenceElement for public void my.package.dao.jpa.JpaDAOSupport.setEm(javax.persistence.EntityManager)
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [my.package.dao.jpa.MyDAOImpl]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [my.package.dao.jpa.MyDAOImpl]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'all' of type [java.util.List]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'em' of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager]
amework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata  Processing injected method of bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO': PersistenceElement for public void my.package.dao.jpa.JpaDAOSupport.setEm(javax.persistence.EntityManager)
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory          Creating [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap]
g.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy  Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [my.package.dao.jpa.MyDAOImpl@1298826]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Finished creating instance of bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'my.package.service.MyService'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Creating instance of bean 'my.package.service.MyService'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Eagerly caching bean 'my.package.service.MyService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Getting BeanInfo for class [my.package.service.impl.MyServiceImpl]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [my.package.service.impl.MyServiceImpl]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
g.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults  Found bean property 'myDAO' of type [my.package.dao.MyDAO]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO'
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Invoking init method  'method1' on bean with name 'my.package.service.MyService'
anagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler  Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils  Closing JPA EntityManager
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1989b5: defining beans [org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,my.package.dao.MyDAO,my.package.service.MyService]; root of factory hierarchy
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'my.package.dao.MyDAO': [my.package.service.MyService]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'transactionManager': [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': [org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0]
k.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'entityManagerFactory': [transactionManager, my.package.dao.MyDAO]
mework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter  Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
ingframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean  Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'null'
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader       Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'my.package.service.MyService' defined in class path resource [config/persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
```

I'd like to understand why the transactions are not opened, and how could i solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: The configuration you list seems correct and using `@Transactional` in the service layer is a best practice. So far everything seems fine, you will have to show more code (Java and/or XML) for us to find the error

Comment: When the application starts up, what is logged by AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource (at DEBUG)? You should see something like... Adding transactional method 'method1' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''

Comment: Also make sure your service is declared in the same application context as `<tx:annotation-driven>`.

Comment: That last log entry seems to indicate that you don't have a Session. I'm more familiar with Hibernate using AnnotationSessionFactoryBean, so I don't know how JPA deals with acquiring a Hibernate Session

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, in fact the problems were

- config problem
- transactions can't be openned on the init-method, because no (transactional) proxy is created yet.

**For 1.:**

```
    <!-- transaction manager for use with a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access to a single datasource -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" 
/>

<!-- uses the persistence unit defined in the META-INF/persistence.xml JPA configuration file -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${dataSource.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${dataSource.url}"
    p:username="${dataSource.username}"
    p:password="${dataSource.password}"
/>
```

**about 2. :**

- using a TransactionTemplate
- register an ApplicationListener and listen for ContextRefreshedEvent

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like it could possibly be one of:

1. Your `@Transactional` annotation is on an interface, and you're using the wrong type of proxy
2. Your calling the `@Transactional` method internally

[`@Transactional` docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the `@Transactional` annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the `@Transactional` annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact that Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies (`proxy-target-class="true"`) or the weaving-based aspect (`mode="aspectj"`), then the transaction settings are not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.
>
> **Note**
> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with `@Transactional`.

EDIT:
You should also check the docs for the LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean you're using. Based on my quick read there, it seems you're missing a property that might be needed. It also mentions some specifics about weaving, which may be playing a role here.

[Spring ORM JPA LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-lemfb)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the old proxy problem. -- Use real AspectJ weaving instead of this Spring Proxy stuff to get rid of the problem (for ever).

@see: [Spring: Annotation-driven Transaction Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155991/spring-annotation-driven-transaction-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above reasons, this could also be an issue with JRE version. Actually I faced the same. The application was running properly in JRE 6, but as I migrated to JRE 7, it raised this exception.

Solution : Specified Tomcat to use JRE 6 explicitly (using Eclipse) instead of JRE 7